# acumatica fixed asset cannot tick depreciation after transactions

Tags: acumatica

While using fixed asset module, we create an asset without ticking the "depreciation" tick box in general/main tab. Then added a capitalisation journal entry for purchase, now we cannot tick the depreciation tick box. Is there any workaround we have missed?

Thanks

Comment: Please open a support case with Acumatica. This site is for programming questions only.